# UIViewController slow to load until touched

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller that's loaded from a segue that's performed when a table row is selected. This view controller is embedded in a navigation controller (& tab bar controller).

I prepare for that segue by setting a new nav controller and getting it's child view controllers, then passing a variable to a specific child.

When I select a row sometimes the app hangs (around 4-5 seconds), and sometimes it fires off right away. I've noticed when it's hanging if I touch the screen the next view will load immediately.

What am I getting caught up on?

edit, code added:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    selectedId = myArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("myId") as Int
    performSegueWithIdentifier("goToExtraDetails", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToExtraDetails" {

        let nextNavVc = segue.destinationViewController as ExtraMenuNavigationViewController

        let nextChildVc = nextNavVc.childViewControllers[0] as ExtraMenuViewController

        nextChildVc.thisId = selectedId

    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: added code as requested

Comment: it seems when I remove the code in the if of the segue.identifier, the view loads nice and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to eliminate the delay by putting the if statement inside a dispatch to the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    if segue.identifier == "goToExtraDetails" {

        let nextNavVc = segue.destinationViewController as ExtraMenuNavigationViewController

        let nextChildVc = nextNavVc.childViewControllers[0] as ExtraMenuViewController

        nextChildVc.thisId = selectedId

    }
})
```

Comment: I have the same issue but this is not working with my application.